# Retrieving content immediately from firebase database on Activity startup

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I have integrated Firebase Database.I want to fetch database data on opening a particular activity.
As per documentation-

> The value event is used to read a static snapshot of the contents at a
>   given path, as they existed at the time of the event. It is triggered
>   once with the initial data and again every time the data changes.
>
> The onChildAdded event is typically used when retrieving a list of
>   items in the Firebase database. Unlike the value event which returns
>   the entire contents of the location, the onChildAdded event is
>   triggered once for each existing child and then again every time a new
>   child is added to the specified path.

As per my understanding both `addValueEventListener` and  `addChildEventListener` can be used to retrieve data and it should get called once everytime listener is attached and then whenever there is a change in data.I tested them one by one by adding listener inside onCreate method.I noticed both of them do get called after activity startup but with a delay of 15-20 seconds.Is this delay normal?Is there anyway i can immediately retrieve content from firebase database on Activity startup?

Comment: I think you should check this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41939769/firebase-on-app-startup-taking-more-than-3-seconds-to-load-data/41954672#41954672

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The delay you are seeing is likely down to retrieving it from the Firebase servers.

https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/android/offline-capabilities

Use offline data to speed this up and keep the important data synced locally for quicker access.