# I want to add the same splash screen across multiple activity in android with less number of codes.?

Tags: android, splash-screen

I want a splash screen to be shown before opening an activity. For that i create a splash screen. But my problem is i have multiple activity in my app for that right now i am using that single splash screen. So what's the correct way to do that either i have to add it to all activity one by one or can be done same at once, then how? what's the way for that?.

Comment: Why do you want to show splash screen before loading any activity? Do you even know the purpose of splash in android?

Comment: yes i know the purpose of splash that's why i'm using it!! And I'm using firebase for my app and my each activity generally take 3-4 sec to load data from there.. which doesn't good. So i'm using splash there to load data in cache in-between...

Comment: you are definitely confused with splash screen. Splash is used in the starting of the app to cover the system delay along with some initial app setup. To show downloads and other heavy tasks Android, iOS, web has something called `ProgressBar` you can definitely put a solid background to it but it will still be called progress bar and will serve your purpose brilliantly.

Comment: (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41939769/firebase-on-app-startup-taking-more-than-3-seconds-to-load-data) splash screen gives a nice look than a progress bar... My app is for child so if I use a splash screen there then this will attract them as well and my data will also download in cache in that time.. from UI perspective  I need to implement like this.. that's why i'm going with splash instead of progressBar..

Comment: nice. but! did you even go through my solution? did you even try what i have posted? first try that and then let me know if your point stands valid or not.

Comment: And yes -> http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41939769/firebase-on-app-startup-taking-more-than-3-seconds-to-load-data -> this is the link that you yourself shared. Did you even go through this? It too say the same what I said, Splash screen is to rectify the delay in app startup but not a replacement for ProgressBar.

Answer (score 0):

Elaborating my comment there, you are confused with the purpose of Splash Screen. As the name says, it should just appear for splash of a second in the beginning and disappear, for further feedback to user to show downloads you have to use `ProgressBar`

Here you can externalize the code for `ProgressBar` to have minimal codes.

**progress_bar_layout.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@color/colorAccent">
    <ProgressBar
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
    <!-- Customize yoiur progress bar screen here--> 
</RelativeLayout>
```

then include this layout wherever you want

**activity_main.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
    tools:context="com.example.android.myApp.MainActivity"
    tools:showIn="@layout/app_bar_main">

    <include
        android:id="@+id/progress_bar"
        android:visibility="gone"
        layout="@layout/progress_bar_layout" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Hello World!"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

Then in your java class

```
private RelativeLayout progressBar;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    //some code
    progressBar = (RelativeLayout)findViewById(R.id.progress_bar);
    //control parent instead of progress bar only
}

private void beginDownload(){
    progressBar.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    //your download code
}

private void downloadComplete(){
    progressBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    //codes once download is completed
}
```

> P.S. If your design specifically requires some different screen other
>   than rotating progress bar, then use same approach, just change the
>   `progress_bar_layout.xml` to reflect your design, everything else will
>   remain same. **Hence No Concept Of Splash Screen For This Task, Just
>   Progress Bar.**